# Spectrum Radius

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be symmetric positive definite matrix and $\rho(A)$ denotes spectrum radius of $A$. How to prove that $\rho(I-\omega A)<1$ iff $0<\omega<2/\rho(A)$?

Comment: you could use that for a symmetric matrix $\rho(M) < 1$ iff for every $x$ : $\left|x^T M x \right|< ||x||^2$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note, of course, that $A$ necessarily has positive eigenvalues, so all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$ satisfy $0 < \lambda \leq \rho(A)$, with the maximal eigenvalue equal to $\rho(A)$.  The statement on the right is equivalent to the statement that for each eigenvalue $\lambda$, $|1 - \omega \lambda| < 1$.

On the other hand, note that (for positive $\omega$)
$$
|1 - \omega \lambda| < 1 \quad \iff\\
|1/\omega - \lambda| < 1/\omega \iff \\
0 < \lambda < 2/\omega
$$

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer.If $\rho (I-\omega A)<1$ then $\omega \ne 0.$ And $\rho (I-\omega A)<1$ implies that $(I-\omega A-x I)$ is invertible whenever $|x|\geq 1,$ which implies that $I(1-x)/\omega -A $ is invertible whenever $|x|\geq 1,$ whence $|(1-x)/|\omega|>\rho (A).$ Putting $x=-1$ we have $2/|\omega|>\rho.$

Answer (score 0):

Define $G:=I-\omega A.$ Assume that $\rho(G)<1$. Note that $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $A$ iff $1-\omega\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $G$. Since we have $\rho(G)<1$ then $|1-\omega\lambda_i|<1$ for all $\lambda_i$ eigenvalue of $A$. Positive definiteness of $A$ implies $\lambda_i=\rho(A)$ for some $i$. Hence

$$-1<1-\omega\rho(A)<1,$$
$$0<2-\omega\rho(A)<2,$$
$$0<\omega<2/\rho(A).$$

Now assume that $0<\omega<2/\rho(A).$ Then

$$0<\omega\lambda_i<2\lambda_i/\rho(A),$$

$$-2\lambda_i/\rho(A)<-\omega\lambda_i<0,$$
$$-1\le1-2\lambda_i/\rho(A)<1-\omega\lambda_i<1,$$
$$|1-\omega\lambda_i|<1.$$
Hence $\rho(G)<1$.